# React refs on multiple elements through map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code to catch when the dropdown is clicked outside which is working fine :

```
renderTypes() {
    return _.map(this.props.items, (item, index) => {
        return (
                    <div className="ui icon top dropdown" tabIndex="0">
                        <div className={"menu transition" + classe} 
                             tabIndex="-1"
                             ref={node =>  this.node = node }/>
                    </div>
        );
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
}

handleClickOutside(e){
    const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.node);

    if(!domNode || !domNode.contains(e.target)){
        this.setState({open: ""});
    }
}
```

But in fact this is working only on the last dropdown. I'm pretty sure that this is because of ref which is not well given to my div and I would like to know how to use it with a map.

Is my code correct or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign ref within map like `ref={node =>  this.node = node }` the same ref is being overridden and hence the `ref` will only hold the instance of last node. You should instead add a ref to the wrapper around Dropdown items

```
renderTypes() {
    return <div ref={node =>  this.node = node }>{_.map(this.props.items, (item, index) => {
        return (
                    <div className="ui icon top dropdown" tabIndex="0">
                        <div className={"menu transition" + classe} 
                             tabIndex="-1"
                         />
                    </div>
        );
    })}</div>;
}
```